# How get all products by category name in Magento

Tags: magento, categories, product

How to get all products given a category name?

This is how i get all products given a category id

```
$cat_id = 1; // category id
$_productCollection = $product->getCollection()
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array($cat_id)) )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
            ->setCurPage(1)
            ->setPageSize(12);
```

but how do you get by category name?

Answer (score 2):

You can get category id from name by using following code

```
$cat = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'cat_name')->getData();
$cat_id = $cat[0]['entity_id'];
```

Now, use `$cat_id` in product collection to get products filtered by category id

Comment: I already solved my problem before i saw this, but your answer is basically the same logic on my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can filter by name instead of id after joining the field category_name. replacing category_id by category_name should do the trick.

```
/**
* Join regular table field and use an attribute as fk
*
* Examples:
* (‘country_name’, ‘directory/country_name’, ‘name’, ‘country_id=shipping_country’, “{{table}}.language_code=’en’”, ‘left’)
*
* @param string $alias ‘country_name’
* @param string $table ‘directory/country_name’
* @param string $field ‘name’
* @param string $bind ‘PK(country_id)=FK(shipping_country_id)’
* @param string|array $cond “{{table}}.language_code=’en’” OR array(‘language_code’=>’en’)
* @param string $joinType ‘left’
* @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
*/
joinField($alias, $table, $field, $bind, $cond=null, $joinType=’inner’)
```

and filter by category_name instead...

```
$cat_name = "catname"; // category id
$_productCollection = $product->getCollection()
        ->joinField('category_name', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_name', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_name', array('in' => array($cat_name)) )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->setPageSize(12);
```

Comment: can you give me the modifiedd code? i wanna make sure what you mean.

Comment: I edited to give an hint of what to do I'm not 100% sure of the names to use

Answer (score 0):

You want category id from category name right? so, u can use it further. try below.
$cat = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Category_Name_Here');
$cat->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();

Comment: I want all products given a category name

Comment: $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($cat->getFirstItem()->getEntityId())
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');